# Book that tracked the life of two objects over centuries

Tags: identification-request

Many years ago I read a rather interesting book that tracked the life of two physical objects (a whip and a crown perhaps) over several centuries. The book was given to me as a child by my father, who read it as a child. Napoleon's invasion of Russia plays a role in the book with two characters surviving a winter using the remains of a horse for shelter. I am now trying to find the name of the book and if it is still in print.

I probably read the book back in the 1970s. My father probably read the book in 1920s/1930s. Does that help? Predictably, I read the book in English. Was it originally written in English? I really don't know. I remember it as a reasonably large book, but I am not sure.

Comment: Repost of [this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3607/11259)?

Comment: Bobble, Yes definitely a repost. My hope is that this is the right place to post my question. Of course, it might not be. Where should this question be posted?

Comment: The question is on-topic here. Whether you get an answer is a different problem - someone may be able to find the book, someone may not. See the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for more information that could help narrow down the book. (e.g. we don't know when you or your father were children, so saying that doesn't help us)

Comment: If it weren't for your father's having read the book in the 1920s or 1930s, I would say this sounds like the style of a James Michener novel. He loved to track things and families over centuries in his longer works.

Comment: shoover, So true. When I was younger, I read Tai-Pan and Shōgun both by Clavell. Of course, I read numerous works by Michner as well. These books (along with "The Emerging Japanese Superstate" by Herman Kahn) greatly influenced my view of Asia and Asians. After 50 years, what I learned from these books still stands out.

Comment: _The Path of the King_ (1921) by John Buchan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Path_of_the_King) traces the story of a gold torque, later refashioned as a ring, down the centuries. Probably not the book you are looking for, though, as the invasion of Russia does not feature. "A dead horse on an ice-floe" is mentioned, but only in passing.

Comment: I don't think "The Path of the King" is the correct book. As I remember it (from a long time ago), the whip and the crown didn't change much over the centuries.